# C# changed list to hashset and now getting error

Tags: c#

I'm making multiplayer game and i have some problems with adding player in game. I changed list to hashset because i dont want dublicated values. First making new hashset: `public static HashSet<Players> PlayersList = new HashSet<Players>();`

Players Class:

```
public class Players
{
    public int ID;
    public string IP;
    public string name;
    public int locationX;
    public int locationY;
    public int locationXLatest;
    public int locationYLatest;
    public int dir;
    public bool PlayerConnected = false;
    public bool PlayerDisconnected = false;
}
```

Addind player in game using for (ERROR):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Globals.Globals.PlayersList.Count; i++)
{
    var ent = Globals.Globals.PlayersList[i]; //<-- ERROR! WORKING IF USING LIST BUT GETTING THIS ERROR IF I'M USING HASHSET: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Players>

    if (ent.name != null && !ent.PlayerConnected && !ent.PlayerDisconnected)
    {
        ent.PlayerConnected = true;
        //My secret code :D Addind player in game :3
    }
}
```

Addind player in game using foreach (WORKING, BUT IF LIST MODIFIED -> CRASH)

```
foreach (var ent in Globals.Globals.PlayersList)
{
    if (ent.name != null && !ent.PlayerConnected && !ent.PlayerDisconnected)
    {
        ent.PlayerConnected = true;
        //My secret code :D Addind player in game :3
    }
}
```

Working fine if using list, but new list items is spamming alltime because player adding is added loop where check if connect is open. Or its possible using list but not getting doublicated values? I try make check is player added, but then players not showing...

Comment: No need to initialize `PlayerConnected` and `PlayerDisconnected` to `false`. they already are `false` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding .ToArray() at the end of your call to cache the list when iterating?

```
foreach (var ent in Globals.Globals.PlayersList.ToArray())
...
```

Furthermore if you want to ensure that players are unique per ID you could add them to a Dictionary with the ID as key instead, or implement hashcode for the Player class.

```
Dictionary<int, Players> PlayersList;
```

And then iterate over them like this:

```
foreach (var ent in Globals.Globals.PlayersList.Values)
```

Again, you might have to use .ToArray() if you are modifying PlayersList inside the loop.

Comment: THANKS!!! ITS NOW ADDIND PLAYER ONCE <33 But its showin once time "An item with the same key has already been added." error... I want hide it :(

Comment: You can check before adding if the player is already in the dictionary. Use `PlayersList.ContainsKey(ID)`

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` do not contain an Indexer. and since you don't care what the `Player` position in the set is, you could simply use `foreach` instead, it will save you some code lines as well:

```
foreach (var player in Globals.Globals.PlayersList)
{
    if (player.name != null && !player.PlayerConnected && !player.PlayerDisconnected)
    {
        player.PlayerConnected = true;
        //My secret code :D Addind player in game :3
    }
}
```